# Live filter on table not working in Django template

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am interested in a live filter on table, exactly like this example      http://jsfiddle.net/giorgitbs/52ak9/1/ .  I have a Django project using the Bootstrap framework.  I have the below code, verbatim from the example from what I can see.  However the filter is not applied to my table.

```
{% extends 'pim/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Test table{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    (function ($) {

        $('#filter').keyup(function () {

            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('.searchable tr').hide();
            $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
                return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();

        })

    }(jQuery));

 });
</script>

<h1>Test table</h1>

<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filter</span>
    <input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here...">
</div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Default</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="searchable">
        <tr>
            <td>EUR</td>
            <td>EURO</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GBP</td>
            <td>Pound</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GEL</td>
            <td>Georgian Lari</td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>USD</td>
            <td>US Dollar</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing in my template for this to work?

Comment: I just tried to download the latest jQuery (1.11.3 and 2.1.4) and replace the version that was included in Bootstrap, unfortunately this doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the script was indeed incorrect, but hadn't to do with the HTML code: it needed to be after the jQuery code (which makes perfect sense...).

Answer (score 1):

try to put the jquery code right after the html code, because 'filter' id should exist first in order to apply the keyup event later. Tell me how it goes.

Comment: I have changed the location of the top `<script>` block to directly after the `<table>` block, but there is no difference.  I had also placed the JS in a separate file and loaded it with a `<script src>` tag (like the query.min.js file), but it made no difference.

Comment: Glad i could help somehow =)